# How to build object instead of array with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller which adds times to an associative array using a function:

```
crtl.items = [];
ctrl.build_array = function (code, item) {
  crtl.items[code] = item;
}
```

My problem is associative arrays are problematic in javascript so this works:

```
<div>
  <p>{{ctrl.items['a']}}</p>
<div>
```

But this doesn't:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items">
  <p>{{item}}</p>
</div>
```

How can I change my angular function so that it adds items to a objects rather than an associative array?

Comment: Array or Object?  Arrays use ordinal index like 0, 1, 2, and objects can use almost anything as index like numbers/strings, and are like an associative array.  So what happens when `ctrl.items = {};` ?

Answer (score 3):

Objects and associative arrays are the same things in JavaScript. And you'd better not confuse an engine by providing it with a false hint on type; this...

```
crtl.items = {}; // plain object, not an array!
ctrl.build_array = function (code, item) {
  crtl.items[code] = item;
}
```

... is enough, as you can actually iterate over objects with `ng-repeat` too:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, item) in ctrl.items">
  <p>{{item}}</p>
</div>
```

Quoting [**the docs**](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.6/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties):

> You need to be aware that the JavaScript specification does not define
>   the order of keys returned for an object. (To mitigate this in Angular
>   1.3 the `ngRepeat` directive used to sort the keys alphabetically.)
>
> Version 1.4 removed the alphabetic sorting. We now rely on the order
>   returned by the browser when running `for key in myObj`. It seems that
>   browsers generally follow the strategy of providing keys in the order
>   in which they were defined, although [there are exceptions when keys
>   are deleted and reinstated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Cross-browser_issues).
>
> If this is not desired, the recommended workaround is to convert your
>   object into an array that is sorted into the order that you prefer
>   before providing it to ngRepeat. You could do this with a filter such
>   as `toArrayFilter` or implement a `$watch` on the object yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make  ctrl.items an object like:

```
      ctrl.items  = {}
```

Use like this:

```
          <div ng-repeat="(code, value) in ctrl.items">
            <p>{{value}}</p>
          </div>
```

Comment: My function produces an array formatted like this `[mb: "1Mango Bottle", jb: "1Junk Bottle"]` and ng-repeat will not iterate over it. Even when I use `(code, value) in ctrl.items`

Comment: Have you tried yet? I'm pretty sure it works. @JaredWhipple